# HTTP Status 404 - на мой сервлет

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, tomcat

Хотел создать первый, самый простой сервлет, но что-то пошло не туда. Есть проект на maven, есть настроенный tomcat, стандартную jsp запускает нормально, но мой сервлет не хочет.
Вот мой сервлет -

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet{

     @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("Hello Vlad!!!");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

вот дерево
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>zherikhov</groupId>
  <artifactId>shopplus</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>shopplus Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>shopplus</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Покажите файл конфигурации

Comment: @YuriiS я добавил

Comment: А конфиг на `xm`l или в `java` классе можете показать ?